# Combination of two columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need all combination of two columns.

First column:

```
+----+
|  4 |
|  8 |
+----+
```

Second column:

```
+----+
|  5 |
|  6 |
+----+
```

And the output should look like this:

```
+-----+-------+
|   4 |     5 |
|   4 |     6 |
|   8 |     5 |
|   8 |     6 |
+-----+-------+
```

Is it possible?

SOLUTION:

Third column:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($F$1)+1>COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B),"",INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW()-ROW($F$1))/COUNTA(B:B)+1)))
```

Fourth column:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($F$1)+1>COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B),"",INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$1),COUNTA(B:B))+1))
```

Comment: Without a Macro? You could copy and paste...

Comment: Sory, but in my real data is not possible.

Comment: This is only a sample. Columns are much longer.

Comment: Ok this is my real data. Can you help me with macro or function to create the output?

Comment: If you want a "macro" you should tag your question as such.  put in "vba" or "excel-vba"

Answer (score 1):

**Third column:**

=INDEX($A:$A,ROUNDUP(ROWS(C$1:C1)/COUNTA($B:$B),0))

Fill down until 0 appears

**Fourth Column:**

(Not the most elegant formula, but it does the job)

=INDIRECT("B"&IF(ROW()-COUNT(B:B)*ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/COUNTA(B:B),0)<>0,ROW()-COUNT(B:B)*ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/COUNTA(B:B),0),COUNT(B:B)))

Fill down until last row in Column C

This supposes your data is in columns A and B, there is no blank cells between values and your output will be in columns C and D.

### FOR CZECH VERSION:

**Third column:**

=INDEX($A:$A;ROUNDUP(ŘÁDKY(C$1:C1)/POČET2($B:$B);0))

Fill down until 0 appears

**Fourth Column:**

=NEPŘÍMÝ.ODKAZ("B"&KDYŽ(ŘÁDEK()-POČET(B:B)*ROUNDDOWN(ŘÁDEK()/POČET2(B:B);0)<>0;ŘÁDEK()-POČET(B:B)*ROUNDDOWN(ŘÁDEK()/POČET2(B:B);0);POČET(B:B)))

Fill down until last row in Column C

You should expect all answers in Stackoverflow to be given in English and with non-Europe standards. Translation courtesy of [Excel Translator](http://en.excel-translator.de/translator/).

I also don't know, if the different arguments are separated by `;` in Czech Version as, for example, it's in another countries in Europe. If that doesn't work, just change them with `,` again.

Comment: Thank you, but in columns C and D is not output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kHfTDkjhgEEdKxrrQti0b4zeP3qylM6Kt3bzMGEHY2g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Aha, but in my excel It does not work...

Comment: Which version and language are you using? Are you in Europe?

Comment: Czech republic  in Europe

Comment: on docs.google.com it works beautifully

Comment: Edits done to answer for Czech

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, but now I noticed that the output is not what I need. Now, there are duplicate rows. I need output that shows above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94498/discussion-between-agustin-and-kevas).